# html after ng-include not being rendered

Tags: angularjs

tempHeader.html is rendered fine but then rendering seems to stop?

What am I missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>

  <!-- Angular JS Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    I am here

    <ng-include src="'tempHeader.html'"/>

    I am also here  <!-- not rendered -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't close the tag in itself.

`<ng-include src="tempHeader.html"></ng-include>` should do the trick.